# Multiply each column of a data frame by the corresponding value of a vector

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have the following data frame and vector:

```
dframe <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:9,3))
vector <- c(2,3,4)
```

I would like to multiply each column of `dframe` by the corresponding value of `vector`. This won't do:

```
> vector * dframe
  V1 V2 V3
1  2  8 14
2  6 15 24
3 12 24 36
```

each **row** of `dframe` is multiplied by the corresponding value of `vector`, not each **column**. Is there any idiomatic solution, or am I stuck with a `for` cycle?

Comment: What about `t(t(dframe) * vector)` ?

Comment: This is a duplicate. One method is `df * rep(vec, each=nrow(df))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is another option using `sweep`

```
sweep(dframe, 2, vector, "*")
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  2 12 28
#2  4 15 32
#3  6 18 36
```

---

Or using `col`

```
dframe*vector[col(dframe)]
```

Comment: I like the second option best. I think it's faster, if you get hooked and want to try it out on a sequence of similar operations :) In my case, after multiplying `dframe` by  `vector`, I also want to add  `center` to it (another vector). With this approach I can just write  `vec2mat <- col(dframe);  dframe*vector[vec2mat] + center[vec2mat]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map`:

```
as.data.frame(Map(`*`, dframe, vector))

#  V1 V2 V3
#1  2 12 28
#2  4 15 32
#3  6 18 36
```