# how to multiply each row with a scaler in corresponding column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data, the last column is 1 and -1 . I want to multiply each row with coresponding last column element (1 or -1).

```
    col1.   col2.  col3.   col4
      3       2     4        1
      4        3    8        -1
      2        3     4       1 
      3         4     1       -1
```

output:

```
    col1.   col2.  col3.   col4
      3        2      4         1
      -4        -3    -8        -1
      2         3      4        1 
      -3         -4     -1       -1
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate as it is just a multiplication essentially - `dat[-ncol(dat)] <- dat[-ncol(dat)] * dat[[ncol(dat)]]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189087/multiply-each-column-of-a-data-frame-by-the-corresponding-value-of-a-vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. We can use `mutate_at` and specify the column to multiply as follows.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>% mutate_at(vars(-col4), list(~ . * col4))
dat2
#   col1. col2. col3. col4
# 1     3     2     4    1
# 2    -4    -3    -8   -1
# 3     2     3     4    1
# 4    -3    -4    -1   -1
```

**Data**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "col1.   col2.  col3.   col4
      3       2     4        1
      4        3    8        -1
      2        3     4       1 
      3         4     1       -1",
                  header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Also, base R `dat[-4] <- dat[-4] *dat[,4]`

Comment: @akrun Thanks for sharing. Base R is more concise in this case.

Comment: @akrun I couldn't get your method

Comment: Try this: `dat[, -4] <- dat[, -4] * dat[, 4]`.  And next time, please be more specific about your data type in your question.

Comment: Looking your question again, I noticed your question tagged as `dataframe`. This is why people including me assume you are working on a data frame in the begining.